# Backbone - findWhere : How to find a model by querying for a nested object

Tags: backbone.js

Here's my collection's sample set:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "class": "3",
    "marks": {
        "maths": 70,
        "science": 85
    }
},
{
    "name": "Ron",
    "class": "3",
    "marks": {
        "maths": 80,
        "science": 90
    }
}
```

With Backbone's findWhere, I'm able to get the model given the query like this:

```
Coln.findWhere({"name": "Ron"});
```

But how do I query the model based on maths mark? The below code doesn't seem to work:

```
Coln.findWhere({"marks.maths": 80});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Collections have various [Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) mixed into them. In particular, there is [`find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) which lets you specify a predicate function so you could do something like this:

```
Coln.find(function(m) { return m.get('marks').maths === 80 })
```

If you wanted to find all the models that matched, use [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter).